# Load google map libraries in separate HTTP requests

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm wondering if there is a way to load google map libraries in separate HTTP requests? My interest is to know if it is possible to do it as I can't find any related doc...

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?language=en&sensor=false"></script>
<!--
    First map which does not need extra google map libraries
-->
<script type="text/javascript" scr="library_url"></script>
<!--
    Second map which needs extra google map libraries
-->
```

Thanks